# Can I use "CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_name();" [or similar] (oracle stored procedure)

Tags: oracle11g

Can I use

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_name();
```

[or similar]....., instead of

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE table_name();
```

While creating an oracle stored procedure. to save the space that global temp table creates, or suggest any other way possible.

Comment: A global temporary table will exist in the database and consume very little space until you put data into it.  That data will be LOCAL to your session.  Minimal resources are allocated to empty temp tables so what are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention database version you use. If it is 18c, then you can create a *private* temporary table which is memory-based and is dropped at the end of the transaction or the session (depending on the way you create it): `ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION` or `ON COMMIT DROP DEFINITION`.

If it is a lower version, then a global temporary table is the only option if you really want a *temporary* table.

Another option is to create a "normal" table, use it, truncate after you're done with what you do.

However, perhaps the best question is: do you *really* need a temporary table? If your background is MS SQL Server which uses them much, then try to switch to Oracle-ish way of living, most of time without temporary tables. It, actually, depends on what you want to do. If you could explain that, someone might suggest a good approach.